# Update Task Project Online using JQuery & Rest API

Tags: ms-project, project-server, project-online

I have my JSON string which contains the parameter I want to Update

```
var oCreateTaskParameter = JSON.stringify
(
 {
  "parameters":
     {   
       "Custom_x005f_5ef4c0a0aaa1e61180cc00155d302506": "Testing"
     }
 }
);
```

Below is my Ajax Query

```
$.ajax({
url:'<<site url>>/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects(<<guid>>)/Draft/Tasks/GetById(<<guid>>)',
type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: oCreateTaskParameter,
   headers: {
             "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             "X-RequestDigest": '<<Request Digest>>'
            },
 success:function(data){

},
error:function(data){
console.log(data);
},
async:false
});
```

But i get an error as **"The parameter parameters does not exist in method GetById"**

I am sending the parameters parameter, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the endpoint you are using only supports GET (as noted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj669951.aspx)), and will just retrieve the content of a DraftTask. I think you'll want to use the MERGE verb with this URL:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('projectid')/Draft/Tasks('taskid')
```

Documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj669340.aspx).